# Query Alternate Table if record not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two queries as bellow

```
SELECT  i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  IncidentLikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId
```

And

```
SELECT  i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  incidentreportlikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentReportSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId
```

I need to prepare a query with `WITH` clause such that within the clause either of the two query runs and then this view can be joined with another table.

Can you guys please suggest how I can proceed ?

I have tried `UNION` but that doesn't work for me. I am looking for something using `IFEXISTS` or `EXISTS` where - some like bellow :

```
WITH IncidentCategory AS (

SELECT i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  IncidentLikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL)
OR
(SELECT  i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  incidentreportlikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentReportSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId)
)
```

A little more to get the idea : for each of the rows [incidentid] if the the first query returns any result - it should show otherwise the second query result should show

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correctly you have to run first query and if it has no results the second one should be run.

In fact you can union the both queries. The amount of rows in the second one should depend on the first. If count(*) for the first returns >0 the second query rows are included. See the example

```
SELECT  i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  IncidentLikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId

UNION

SELECT  i.IncidentId, rl.Description Category FROM incident i
JOIN  incidentreportlikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
JOIN IncidentReportSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId = ls.SeverityId
JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId
join (select count(*) as count 
      FROM incident i
      JOIN  IncidentLikelihood l ON i.IncidentId = l.IncidentId
      JOIN IncidentSeverity s ON i.IncidentId = s.IncidentId
      JOIN LikelihoodSeverity ls ON l.LikelihoodId = ls.LikelihoodId AND s.SeverityId =       ls.SeverityId
      JOIN RiskLevel rl ON ls.RiskLevelId = rl.riskLevelId) q1_copy on q1_copy.count=0
```

Comment: If the First query has result it should return the the result - if it doesn't return anything then the second query should execute and return the result. Please note that Count is for each of the row returned.

Comment: @ElectricLlama q1_copy.count=0

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit!